# Data appended to multiple dict values instead of one

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary, python-3.8

```
driver_data_form = {
    'forc_day_off':[],
    'pref_day_off':[],
    'pref_shift':{"day"+str(i):None for i in range(1,15)},
    'route_data':[]
}
```

So I am creating the dict ***driver_data*** (seen below) by using ***driver_data_form*** (seen above)

```
driver_data = {str(i):driver_data_form for i in range(1,12)}
```

and accordingly populating it :

```
loop_list = [str(i) for i in range(1,13)]
    
    
1 for specific_driver in loop_list:
2     for driver in forced_day_off_data:
3         for day in driver:
4             if driver[day]=='1' and day != "driverid":
5                 driver_data[specific_driver]['forc_day_off'].append(day)
```

***forced_day_off_data*** looks like:

[image]

But for some reason, after the above loop is executed once (lines 2-5), and by placing a break point in line 2, I am getting all 11 values of my ***driver_data[forc_day_off]*** dictionary populated, instead of only the first one. It appears that the values of the first key are copied to all the rest of the values:[image]

I debugged this piece of code many times and this behavior makes no sence to me? What could be causing this and how can I fix it?

Comment: Please add editable example data and the end result that you expect to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is that python is using references to dicts and lists. When you do this

```
driver_data = {str(i):driver_data_form for i in range(1,12)}
```

It basically sets the same dict reference for all your keys so when you change one value you actually update for all the other keys since it's the same dict

For your code to work you need to do this:

```
driver_data = {str(i):{
   'forc_day_off':[],
   'pref_day_off':[],
   'pref_shift':{"day"+str(j):None for j in range(1,15)},
   'route_data':[]
   } for i in range(1,12)}
```

This way you create a new dict for each element and you will update only the specific dict.

See this [this link](https://realpython.com/python-pass-by-reference/) to better understand the difference.